# Angular2 material sidenav - changing rtl/ltr direction dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material2, right-to-left

I'm trying to change my layout dynamically according to users' language selection and switch from LTR to RTL on the fly.

I'm using Angular 2 rc6, material 2.0.0-alpha.9-3

It looks like when the page is loaded, it works perfectly with either rtl or ltr. 
However, when it's changed dynamically from within the app (see plunker), the direction changes but the generated element md-sidenav-content has a miscalculated margin-right and margin-left.

Digging further, I managed to see that the _dir object has an eventEmitter that should watch for on change events of _dir and recalculate the margins

@angular/material/sidenav/sidenav.js:

```
_dir.dirChange.subscribe(function () { return _this._validateDrawers(); });
```

But it's never called when changing the direction dynamically.
Although, _dir holds the correct value when page is being loaded for the first time, whether its ltr or rtl.

Finally, here's a plunker to demonstrate the behaviour:

http://plnkr.co/edit/o8lXWC?p=preview

I suspect I'm not using _dir correctly but not managed to figure out what's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at source code `Dir` directive

```
@Input('dir') _dir: LayoutDirection = 'ltr';
```

- https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-alpha.9/src/lib/core/rtl/dir.ts#L19-L43

As you can see you're changing `_dir` property instead of `dir` setter:

```
set dir(v: LayoutDirection) {
  let old = this._dir;
  this._dir = v;
  if (old != this._dir) {
    this.dirChange.emit(null);
  }
}
```

So i think your solution should be like:

**view**

```
<md-sidenav-layout fullscreen dir="ltr" #root="$implicit">

<select #langSelect (change)="changeLang(langSelect.value, root)">
```

**component**

```
changeLang(lang, root: Dir) {
  this.translate.use(lang);
  root.dir = lang == "fr" ? "rtl" : "ltr";
}
```

This way you can omit `direction: string` property on your component.

And one note:

```
translate: TranslateService; //it's redundant `private translate: TranslateService` does it
direction: string; // omit it

constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  this.direction = "ltr"; // omit it
  translate.addLangs(["en", "fr"]);
  translate.setDefaultLang('en');

  let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
  translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
  this.translate = translate; // it's redundant
}
```

Here's your **[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qmOMzr?p=preview)**

If you think that this is the wrong decision then check this

- https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-alpha.9/src/demo-app/demo-app/demo-app.html#L42-L48

Hope this will help you!

Comment: This looks promising!
I'll have to play a while with it since my app is not that simplified as the plunker.
Thanks for the lead, I'll update on the results.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much for getting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to use the "end" and "start" align attribute to solve the problem, but I don't know why it's not possible.
I think a possible solution is that you "play" a bit with the NgStyle and the margin-right as I show in the following Plnkr

```
[ngStyle]="{'margin-right': move}"
```

[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CPzcSUDgw4KZ9Ml1j9Ko)

Hope this could be useful.

Comment: The thing is that this might work on the surface (if I do not have a lot of content on my page) but the main issue is that the generated element of md-sidenav-content that's containing everything is still with an incorrect margin-left, so my content can never reach the full length of the page.
See screenshot of what I mean.
![Margin screenshot](https://s21.postimg.org/52bkz5rjb/margins.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what I did with angular1 also works with angular 2.
That is just adding a CSS:

```
md-sidenav {
    left: initial;
    right: 0;
}
md-sidenav.md-closed {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
```

To now have it only for those with rtl-direction, adding a class/attribute to the body and then only selecting that, would be sufficient.