# How To Change Angular Material 2 direction To RTL

Tags: angular, right-to-left, angular-material2

I Want Create **RTL** Template With Angular Material 2
But، I do not know How To Do This Work?
Please Help Me;

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40147248/angular2-material-sidenav-changing-rtl-ltr-direction-dynamically

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use rtl as attribute

```
dir='rtl'
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0dVDhcvFJKbMexoOoIEC?p=preview)

Go to index.html , you'll find :

```
<body >
   <chips-overview-example dir="rtl">Loading Material Docs example...</chips-overview-example>
</body>
```

Comment: No If Use dir, Commix My inputs

Comment: What  do you mean?

Answer (score 13):

you should add attribute `dir=rtl` to `<html>` tag, Because angular material.js code using this `document.dir` to distinguish layout direction

Comment: @Wael Jazmaty `<html dir="rtl">`is not allowed, but `<body dir="rtl">` is OK.

Answer (score 3):

if you wish to change All element's directions in website, Use the following style (called `Universal selector`) in your `styles.css` file.

```
* {
    direction: rtl;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have published a library that works well with material bi-direction solution by using `scss` mixins check it out:

https://github.com/10bis/ngx-bdir

Answer (score 1):

Angular material uses the selector`[dir=rtl]` for some elements in its css, for example:

```
[dir=rtl] .mat-form-field {
   text-align: right;
}
```

Therefore consider adding `dir=rtl` attribute to your `html` tag:

```
<html dir="rtl">
```